# How to Delete Program exe file after closing program

Tags: c#, windows, formclosing

What I'm trying to do is once the user closes my program, I want the program to automatically delete the exe file. This is what I have but when I close the program I get an error that the path is not accessible, and I assume it's because at the second it is being used and can't delete.

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Application.ExecutablePath;
        File.Delete(path);
    }
```

If anyone knows how to either execute the code once the program is fully closed or how to modify this code to make it do that, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You can't delete yourself

Comment: Check this out, see if it gives you some optional ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245201/how-can-i-make-my-net-application-erase-itself

Comment: Yes one of the options worked perfectly, C0d3r's answer worked. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could execute a powershell command within C# to delete the file for you:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
   {
      PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Remove-Item param($param1)");
      PowerShellInstace.AddParameter("param1", Application.ExecutablePath)
   }
}
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/